# RPM to DEB conversion using alien. Setting DEB specific metadata

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, rpm, deb, alien

I have an RPM package which I converted to Debian package using alien. When I try to install it on ubuntu using ubuntu software center it cribs and throws warnings like maintainer name/address malformed(it gets installed w/o any errors warnings when I use dpkg -i command).

My question is where do I set the maintainer name and address(and other debian specific metadata) while building the RPM package, so that alien will set it in the debian package?

Answer (score 5):

To set the maintainer email address, you can use this syntax:

```
sudo env EMAIL="xxx@mail.com" alien --to-deb the_file.rpm
```

Comment: anybody test this ?, I am also having the same issue.